# Android maps V2 - The method flat(boolean) is undefined for the type MarkerOptions

Tags: android, maps, marker, flat

I have an android app with Android Maps V2. Adding markers to it is no problem but I can't seem to make the marker flat.
When I use this piece of example code

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(50, 50))
                    .flat(true));
```

it gives me the error *The method flat(boolean) is undefined for the type MarkerOptions*.

I have the following in my manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

I can't seem to find why it behaves like flat markers don't exist. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an older version of the Play Services SDK. Download the latest from the SDK Manager, then make sure that your project is using this latest version.

Comment: You are probably right seeing as I cannot think of anything else that could be the problem. Thanks!